# Moving javascript data series to html data attribute breaks Highchart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm trying to add Highcharts chart to a Rails app, following this example

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked

Everything works fine when I use javascript to configure the chart, but as the content will be dynamic I want to move the series data onto a data attribute.

I've modified one line in the function (see view options at the link above)

```
series: $('#container').data('chart')
```

and in the view

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%;height:172px;" data-chart='<%= @data %>' ></div>
```

in the controller

```
@data = [{
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
            }, {
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
            }, {
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
            }]
```

Now instead of displaying the correct chart as in the example, I have a very messy chart with around 100 data series.

Is there a difference in the way this data array is handled under javascript and ruby that would cause this discrepancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the data to the client in a `content_tag` in the view and rename @data to be @my_data:

```
<%= content_tag "div", id: "chart_data", data: {my_data: @my_data} do %>
<% end %>
```

Reload the page, open the JavaScript console, and use jQuery to see if the JavaScript objects are formatted properly:

```
$('#chart_data').data('my_data')
```

In a realistic example, you will want to pass a collection of Ruby objects to the client and this technique is suitable for converting an array of Ruby objects to an array of JS objects.  There is a good [RailsCast on passing data to JS](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript).

Comment: well, that worked, but I don't understand why. how does rendering this as a content_tag rather than directly coding a div affect the way the data attributes are constructed?

Comment: @AndyHarvey - I think the `data: {my_data: @my_data}` calls `to_json` on `@my_data` at some point.  `data-chart=<%= @data.to_json %>` might also work.  Use jQuery to inspect the difference between both solutions.  If you come up with any more info, let me know because I am interested.  Thanks!